# Conflict between Excel and Matlab using actxserver

Tags: excel, matlab, range, server, conflict

I have a problem using actxserver in MATLAB.

I did a script that read data on several sheets in a workbook. This script works fine on my computer, but when a colleague ran it, MATLAB return an error whenever I try to use the Range method.
In fact, MATLAB want to use the function range of the Statistics toolbox instead of the method Range in Excel....

I use the Range method as such : `Sheet.Cells.Range(...)` with Sheet a member of the Sheets collection...

Can anyone explain me why this happens?

Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: Ummm... just for troubleshooting, do you have the code?. Remember that these functionalities are not Matlab's but MS Office. And if MS Office is not installed, the code will not run!....

Comment: Just as additional comment... it is possible you do not use the ActiveX?. Maybe use the Matlab 'xlsread' | 'xlswrite', or some XSLT transformations for creating xls docs?. Those ActiveX depends on each machine....

Comment: Actually the code work, it is just the use of the Range method that creates problem. I use other properties and method of Excel before in the code and it worked. 
Yeah I did it using xlsread, it works fine, but this problem is so weird...

Comment: I am quite sure the Excel Application versions are different.. and that causes the problem....